Is it possible to edit the GitHub Issues default description?
When you open a new Issue in GitHub, there are some default placeholder questions. Is it possible to somehow edit those in my repository?
Your post is mostly images. Add additional details to explain the problem and expected results.
Your post is mostly images. Add additional details to explain the problem and expected results.
Your post is mostly images. Add additional details to explain the problem and expected results.
Pic related:

